# -bash: module: command not found while loading module

Tags: linux, module

I am using following command to load module but it is not working.

```
module load $SOME_PATH
```

but i am getting error `-bash: module: command not found` .Do i need to isntall something using sudo apt-get install?

Comment: The `module` command is not a builtin function of the shell, it is implemented by a different package. You will find lots of resources on this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `module` executable for which there seems to be no ready-made package. The documentation suggests that you build from source.

When you've built it, make sure that you are either in the directory where your `module` file is, or that it's in your `$PATH`.

Here are the [docs](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/INSTALL.html)